# How to fix "DB Security Groups can no longer be associated with this DB Instance" error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

[This might be a duplicate of this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51164140/elastic-beanstalk-migrate-db-security-group-to-vpc-security-group), but I wanted a separate question for my specific situation. Because none of the found answers on Stackoverflow have helped me so far.

I created an Elastic Beanstalk instance a while ago, complete with RDS instance, by following along with the Setup Wizard. But when I now try to upload new code to it I get the following error:

> Environment update is starting.
>
> Environment health has transitioned from Ok to Info. Application
>   update in progress (running for 2 seconds).
>
> Service:AmazonCloudFormation, Message:Stack named
>   'awseb-e-gmz62hycax-stack' aborted operation. Current state:
>   'UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS' Reason: null
>
> Updating RDS database named: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx failed Reason: DB Security
>   Groups can no longer be associated with this DB Instance. Use VPC
>   Security Groups instead.

In the `Configuration` section of the Elastic Beanstalk, under `Security` or `Database` I can't find any setting for `DB Security Groups`.

If I go to the RDS instance that this Elastic Beanstalk is using, under the `Security group rules` I see two `Security Group - Inbound` rules.

One with a name like:

`awseb-e-abcde12345-stack-AWSEBSecurityGroup-123456ABCDE (sg-1234abcd)`

And the other with a name like:

`rds-awseb-e-abcde12345-stack-awsebrdsdbsecuritygroup-1234567abcdef-abcd (sg-4321dcba)`

And the rest is all: `CIDR/IP - Inbound`.

Am I to remove/replace these `Security Group - Inbound` rules with VPC rules? Do I need to completely build a new Elastic Beanstalk, with other rules? And especially *how* to do this.

Also, all the security groups associated with this elastic beanstalk and RDS appear in the Security Groups section of the VPC Dashboard: `https://eu-west-1.console.aws.amazon.com/vpc/home?region=eu-west-1#securityGroups:`.

I am at a loss here. It feels like this should be very straightforward, since I created this with the Setup Wizard from AWS, but I can't figure it out. Anyone with some idea, please comment or answer, thanks!

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: any solution found? having same issue

Answer (score -3):

The error clearly says, `DB Security Groups can no longer be associated with this DB Instance`.

Earlier in RDS, they were using a separate security group called DB Security group. Now everything moved to VPC security group. If you are using older AWS account, still you can see the DB security groups, but its not working now. So use `VPC security group` instead.

### Best practice:

Launching RDS via Elastic Beanstalk or Cloudformation is not a good practice (particularly for production), because when you delete the CF template it'll remove all of your resources including the DB. And Beanstalk also will do the same on the new deployment.

Comment: How do I identify the difference between a DB or VPC Security Group? They all show up in all security group overviews. And they have a VPC id associated with them. Thanks for taking the time btw!